# How to connect Mobile VLCKit media to chromecast?

Tags: ios, swift, google-chrome, casting, vlc

Could someone provide an example on how to connect Mobile VLCKit iOS framework to chrome cast devices? I mean .. to cast a video from VLC Media Player

Comment: From, very bad memory, I don't think this is how chrome cast works, instead, you provide it a "streaming source" of some kind from which it can play.  I tried this a few years ago and while it "worked", mostly, it was a horrible user XP (I was working on security cameras and it had a 15-20s delay)

Comment: Maybe [Integrate Cast Into Your iOS App](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/ios_sender/integrate) and/or [Google Cast in iOS(Swift) Sender App](https://medium.com/macoclock/google-cast-in-ios-swift-sender-app-24254e6ce507) might be better places to start

Comment: Indeed but I see in VLC repo many mentions about chrome cast so I was expecting something included in the library, maybe it is not, Im gonna check that, thanks!

Comment: They might provide some of the boiler plating - don't know, when I did it, we weren't able to make use of VLC (for many technical reasons)

Comment: The advantage of VLC is that it can play basic all videos that my users may have, not sure if all URLs will be directly playable on chromecast

Comment: I think the problem is, the "device" is playing the video, unlike something like AirPlay, where you basically "stream a screen" (I'm horribly paraphrasing) - so technically, it might be that VLC is acting as the streaming source, I don't know, I'm guessing

Comment: Indeed, when you cast the chromecast (or similar device) will pull the video directly from an URL, that can be hosted in some cloud or a local server that the app may create